# Can you disable panning in ArcGIS story map?

Tags: arcgis-online, pan, story-map

I have a story map set up for a specific small area and I want to keep people from being able to accidentally swipe and end up across the world. Is that possible?

Comment: Might find a solution at https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/intro_navigation.html which I looked for after seeing https://geonet.esri.com/thread/87132

Comment: Which Story Map template did you use to build this template?